# How broad is one DSP engineer's knowledge scope?

Tags: soft-question

How broad is one DSP engineer's knowledge scope?

What I'm trying to understand. How many engineers are needed to develop for example some musical DSP application? For example a digital effects unit.

Perhaps it breaks down into layers though in the sense that the people and groups designing the processors are different from designing the circuitry (or parts of it) are different from those designing the software?

How many people would one need to design a DSP processor?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right forum for this. Still, it's entirely possible for a single developer to create a simple DSP application. Most DSP algorithms are known (unless you're doing something very specific) and if you know how to use them, you will mostly focus on the visual aspect (GUI) of your application.

Comment: @dsp_user Well what'd be a better place to ask?

Comment: @mavavilj probably a nice drink with engineers at a company that works in the fields that you deem interesting – this is really something for personal discussion, and not for internet Q&A.

Comment: Depends. Other than a few low level drivers (Codec, buttons) I wrote the entire software for that thing : https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/T1 :-)